# Replace a number in Netbeans editor with incrementing number

Tags: netbeans, replace, sequence

I have some code in Netbeans 6.1 editor that looks like this

fooString(8) 
 
fooString(8) 
 
fooString(8) 
 
fooString(8) 
 
foostring2(8) 
 
foostring3(8) 
 
foostring4(8) 
 
foostring5(8) 
 
foostring6(8) 
 
foostring7(8) 
 
foostring7(9) 
 
foostring7(10) 
 
foostring7(11) 
 
foostring7(12)

and i want to convert it to
fooString(1) 
 
fooString(2) 
 
fooString(3) 
 
fooString(4) 
 
foostring2(5) 
 
foostring3(6) 
 
foostring4(7) 
 
foostring5(8) 
 
foostring6(9) 
 
foostring7(10) 
 
foostring7(11) 
 
foostring7(12) 
 
foostring7(13) 
 
foostring7(14)

Is there a way e.g with regular expresions or anything else to do the job?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do this programmatically? If not, then I'd do the following

1. Use regular expression to insert a tab around the number so (8) becomes (\t8\t)
2. Copy this to an Excel sheet. The tab would arrange the numbers in a separate column i.e. excel will look something like this.

   ```
         A            B        C
      foostring(      8        )

      foostring1(     8        )

      foostring2(     8        )
   ```

   etc.
3. Now change the values in column B. Just type 1 and 2 in the first 2 rows and drag down to fill the rset of rows.
4. Copy back to netbeans editor and remove the tabs inserted in step 1.